# Printing null in java

Tags: java, printing, null

On execution of following line :

```
    System.out.println(null);
```

the result comes out to be **null** printed on console.

Why does that happen?

Comment: -1 - This question is answered by reading the javadoc.

Answer (score 21):

Telling from the sources of OpenJDK 1.6.0_22:

PrintStream:

```
public void println(Object x) {
    String s = String.valueOf(x);
    synchronized (this) {
        print(s);
        newLine();
    }
}
```

String:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Actually, at least in java version 1.8.0, `System.out.println(null);` should not print `null`. You would get an error saying something like:

*reference to println is ambiguous, both method println(char[]) in PrintStream and method println(String) in PrintStream match*. [image]

You would have to cast as follows: `System.out.println((String)null);` See coderanch post [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/453708/java/java/error-system-println).
I suppose you could also do `System.out.println(null+"");` to accomplish same.

Answer (score 6):

Because that's exactly what the Javadocs say will happen?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(java.lang.String)

> Prints a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is printed.

Answer (score 4):

It's eventually calling `String.valueOf(Object)` which looks like:

```
public static String valueOf(Object obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the javadoc for [PrintStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) I observe (I am quoting here)

> print
>
> public void print(String s)
>
> Print a string. If the argument is null then the string "null" is
>   printed. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes
>   according to the platform's default character encoding, and these
>   bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.
>   Parameters: s - The String to be printed

Hopefully that should answer your question..